# Multipayment Order processing / Refund

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, e-commerce

I am working on an e-commerce application, currently my website is handling only one payment method either Credit card / BML or paypal, 
Now i have to add another payment method i.e. Gift Card. Customer can pay order total from multiple payment methods. e.g
 5 gift cards, 
 1 credit card and multiple gift cards etc

my current db structure is as follows

```
   OrderTable
   --------------------------------------------------
   OrderID | OrderNumber | .. and many more columns 


   OrderPayment Table 
   -----------------------------------------------------------
    ID | OrderID | Payment Mode (CC,Paypal,BML) | Amount |
```

these tables has one to one relation ship, now i need to split the payment mode to multiple payment modes. How i can achieve this by doing minimum changes to my existing architecture.

Secondly when an order is processed with multiple payment methods, how i can handle refunds in order (full refund, partial refund) that how i make sure that the exact amount is refund to the payment mode by which order is originally placed. e.g if customer place $100 order and pay $60 from credit card and $30 from one gift card and $10 from other gift card, when this order is refund how i refund the exact amount to CC and GC(s).

Comment: From the structure you posted I don't see any issue with receiving multiple payments for a single order. The refund logic requires a LOT more information to offer much help there. If it is a full refund it should be pretty straight forward. If it is a partial refund you need to determine the order to process.

Answer (score 0):

A separate solution could be to not see the gift card as a payment method, but rather as a coupon. That way the gift card would be subtracted from the total amount and you would still pay with just one payment method.

In the tools I use these are called Service Line Items (as apposed to product line items) which contain things like shipping costs, discounts, ... and one of the is a gift card.

This should make refunds easier as you will only have one payment in the end. That does mean you will need to create separate logic to refund the coupon.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i must have to use 3rd party GC not coupons.